# Laravel json response not showing custom object data

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;

class ErrorResponse implements Arrayable {

    private $error;

    function __construct($code, $message) {
        $this->error = array('code' => $code, 'message' => $message);
    }

    function toArray() {
        return $this->error;
    }

}
```

Then on the controller I have as a response:

```
$data['message'] = 'hello';
$data['error'] = new ErrorResponse($code, 'Something is bad');
return response()->json($data, $code);
```

On the response I get the following result:

```
{
  "error": {},
  "message": "hello"
}
```

But I was expecting

```
{
  "error": {
       "code": 422,
       "message": "Something is bad"
  },
  "message": "hello"
}
```

Any idea on how to make Laravel responds the contents of the nested object (ErrorResponse)?

Comment: You either need to implement the `JsonSerializable` interface or make $error public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you give a pure `array` to `json()`, Laravel just [passes it straight to `json_encode`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/db5f011d8ba9d0bcb5d768bea9d94688739f5b4c/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php#L60-L68). You will either need to:

1. give the `json()` call an `Arrayable` or `JsonSerializable` object to have Laravel recursively expand the value,
2. make the `$error` a `public` so `json_decode` can use it, or
3. do it yourself, given how simple your example is:

   `$data['error'] = (new ErrorResponse($code, 'Something is bad'))->toArray();`

Comment: Added the interface JsonSerializable and implemented as function jsonSerialize() { return $this->error; }